# IF statement to determine Me.Cancel Option

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am in the process of attempting to control the ESC action depending on a value that is passed into the form.

```
Private Sub SetDefault(ByVal myDefaultBtn As Button)
    If Id = "1" Then Me.CancelButton = Button3
    If Id = "2" Then Me.CancelButton = Button1
    If Id = "" Then Me.CancelButton = Button3
End Sub
```

Is it possible to do what I'm attempting? Currently this does not appear to be working...

Below I have attached a larger portion of my code for perspective.

```
Public Class Issue_Detail
Private DayName As String

Dim Val As String = ""
Dim User As String = ""
Dim Days As String = ""
Dim Id As String = ""
Public Sub New(val As String)
    InitializeComponent()
    Me.Val = val
End Sub

Public Sub New(val As String, user As String, Days As String, Id As String)
    Me.New(val)
    Me.User = user
    Me.Days = Days
    Me.Id = Id
End Sub
Public Property iassist As String
Public Property Day As String
Private Sub SetDefault(ByVal myDefaultBtn As Button)
    If Id = "1" Then Me.CancelButton = Button3
    If Id = "2" Then Me.CancelButton = Button1
    If Id = "" Then Me.CancelButton = Button3
End Sub
Private Sub Issue_Detail_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
```

Comment: What's the question / problem?

Comment: Sorry about that - I appear to have missed the key part out haha. This has now been added and amended above :)

Comment: Do you call the method "SetDefault" anywhere?

Comment: why not just use a Dialog Result Statement along with a Case Statement? and if its a console app then just a ConsoleKeyInfo to get the key input so you can create a result

Comment: MatSnow - No i do not - I am guessing i should? (new to VB haha)

Comment: Werdna - I am not sure what you mean by this? Do you have an example of perhaps what i would write?

Comment: @user3482471 - It depends. If you want the method to be executed then you should call it somewhere :-)

Comment: What's the point of passing `myDefaultBtn` into the `SetDefault` method when you don't even use it?  Also, are you actually calling `SetDefault` anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By putting the below code into my MyBase.Load Sub it has given me the result i needed.

```
    If Id = "1" Then Me.CancelButton = Button2
    If Id = "2" Then Me.CancelButton = Button1
    If Id = "" Then Me.CancelButton = Button3
```